# Measuring the Effect of Public Relations on Scientific Journals Impact Factor?

Tags: journals, communication, social-science

I’m looking at the correlation between communications outreach and a scientific journal’s impact factor/citations. I intern for a communications department at a University’s engineering school and we are trying to motivate more of our scientists to share their publications with us for media and press release. The biggest issue we have with convincing scientists to become interested in this is the lack of quantitative data that shows the benefit of us publicizing their journals. I’ve done some prior research and the most I could find was others acknowledging the lack of research done in this area and proposing that social scientists should look into this. Do you have any suggestions for further reading into this topic, either previous studies done, or potentially how to best go about this research on my own? Potentially what factors would be the most useful to compare between journal articles that we have/have not done press releases for, or if this would even be a useful measure?

Comment: I am confused now. Do you mean publicizing the papers or the journals? Those are two very different things.

Comment: I believe journals.

Comment: That does not make me much less confused, since you are saying "their" journals. Do you mean the journals for which they are editors? Managing editors? Actual owners?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.4269.pdf for individual publications
(from personal experience:  I prefer media office of publisher over the one of the university)

Comment: Journals to which they were an author.

Comment: But you are not an author to a journal. You are an author of a paper and you publish that paper in a journal. And PR for journals would not make much sense coming from others than the journal itself (which probably has a publisher with a department for that specific purpose).

Comment: Ah thank you for that clarification. I'm super new to this and didn't know the difference. So then I guess what I meant to say was that they authored a paper that they published to a journal. An example of something we would do pr work for is http://www.pnas.org/content/113/34/9457.abstract which may give you a better understanding than I can.

Comment: So that is a link to a paper. I am sorry to say this, but if you are this unfamiliar with the difference between a journal and a paper then I have a feeling you might not be the right person for finding out how to do these things (or how big their effect is).

Comment: True, but that's why I'm asking for help. Despite the learning curve it may require, I still want to learn more about this issue. The people around me have used multiple terms interchangeably so I wasn't aware of the difference. Do you know of any previous research on this topic that I could at least get started reading about?

Comment: Impact factor does not measure public relations.  It is not an indicator of much besides citation frequency.

Answer (score 1):

First, a proxy for scientific communication may be seen in *Altmetrics*.

Second, Impact Factors are indicators based on *citations*.

Therefore, you could take a look at the numerous studies that have investigated [correlations between Altmetrics and citations](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=altmetrics%20correlations%20citations).

(By the way: It seems that one cannot find research on the direct correlations between Altmetrics and Impact Factors so easily; the reason behind that may be that Altmetric.com does not allow researchers to analyse Altmetrics on a journal-level, as far as I am aware.)